# keyError in Blazor app when using dictionary with tuple keys

Tags: c#, blazor

I am developing a Blazor WebAssembly application, where I am getting the following exception:

**System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key 'key' was not present in the dictionary.'**

I have a KTmethodData class, which has a Grades dictionary that is used to store the grades for each alternative and parameter. The key in the dictionary is a tuple consisting of an alternative and a parameter name.

In my Razor component, I have a table where I am binding input fields to the values in the Grades dictionary. When the user clicks the "Calculate" button, I am trying to calculate the results using the grades and the parameter weights.

The exception is thrown here:

> @bind-value="@KTmethodData.Grades[(alternative, parameter.Name)]"

**Here is my code:**

```
@foreach (var parameter in KTmethodData.Parameters)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@parameter.Name (@parameter.Weight)</td>
                    @foreach (var alternative in KTmethodData.Alternatives)
                    {
                        <td><input type="number" min="1" max="10" @bind-value="@KTmethodData.Grades[(alternative, parameter.Name)]"></td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
```

**And KTmethodData class:**

```
public class KTmethodData
    {
        public static List<string> Alternatives { get; set; } = new List<string>();

        public static List<(string Name, int Weight)> Parameters { get; set; } = new List<(string Name, int Weight)>();

        public static Dictionary<(string alternative, string parameter), int> Grades { get; set; } = new Dictionary<(string, string), int>();

        public static List<(string Alternative, string Parameter, int Result)> Results { get; set; } = new List<(string Alternative, string Parameter, int Result)>();
    }
```

**When encountering the issue, I tried the following:**

- Double-checking if there are any syntax errors or typos in the code
- Changing the binding of the input tag from @bind to @bind-value to see if it solves the issue
- Researching similar issues online and looking at documentation and tutorials related to Blazor forms and data binding

Can anyone help me understand what is going wrong here and how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Are these `struct`-based `ValueTuple` - or the older `Tuple<>` reference-type? Please show us the full definition of `KTmethodData.Parameters`.

Comment: What is the stack-trace of the `KeyNotFoundException` ? You haven't told us where the exception is coming from...

Comment: Unrelated tip: remove the `set;` parts of those properties - collection properties in .NET should not be settable.

Comment: Where do you populate `KTmethodData` - and what invariants have you established that guarantee that every `KTmethodData.Parameters.Name` _and_ `Alternatives` appear in `Dictionary<(string alternative, string parameter), int> Grades` ?

Comment: @Dai It appears that the KTmethodData object is being populated externally, as it is being accessed directly in the Razor component without being initialized or instantiated in the code shown. The KTmethodData object is being used to render a table with data and to perform calculations based on user input.

Comment: Hi, we really need a [mcve]. We need to be able to reproduce this ourselves to really be able to help you. There can be many things causing this, so details are important (but keep the example _minimal_)

Comment: @TimPovodnik If you're not responsible for populating the `KTmethodData` data then you should validate the data as soon as you receive it - and probably should also create a defensive-copy of the data, that way you can avoid thread-unsafe data mutation.

Comment: @Dai I don't understand why the program is searching for a key in the dictionary uppon bind-value, if the table with input fields when user can then provide a numeric input is not even generated. If I remove this line of code the table is generated but the inputs obv do not work.

Comment: @TimPovodnik I'll admit I'm not too familiar with Blazor so I can't help you w.r.t. `@bind-value`.

Comment: `@bind` needs something that is at least defined, if the key doesn't lead to anything, add a value for this key. It doesn't care from where the value comes, would it be an int directly, a list or a dictionary like you. It just needs a spot from where to get the value and to assign to, which you don't provide if the spot doesn't exist.